# yarn/npm start gives permission error with local dev server create-react-app

Tags: linux, npm, sudo, npm-start, yarn-v2

Whenever I try to start the development server, I have to do so with `sudo yarn start`.

This is obviously not preferable.

If I do it without `sudo`, I get the following error:

```js
Starting the development server...

node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn firedragon ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn firedragon',
  path: 'firedragon',
  spawnargs: [ 'http://localhost:3001' ]
}
```

I tried changing permissions of `npm` binaries in `/usr/bin/` and got myself into a whole `sudo` permissions debacle that I thankfully got myself out of.

I also tried to wipe every trace of `yarn`, `npm`, and `node` from my machine and reinstalled everything to no avail.

If anyone has any answers, please, I could use your help.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade with this command: npm install react-scripts@2.1.8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).